doubt regarding class handle in system verilog
I am unable to understand what actually the assignment smpl=e_smpl; does. I thought that by doing so sample class handle will also point to the ext_sample but it is not the case as  smpl.print(); is invoking the task defined in sample class not the ext_smpl class. So what does  smpl=e_smpl; actually does. How is it different from smpl=new();
class sample;
  int a;
  int b;
  task print();
    $display("printing from parent class");
    $display("a=%0d",a);
    $display("b=%0d",b);
  endtask
endclass

class ext_sample extends sample;
  task print();
    $display("printing from child class");
    $display("a=%0d",a);
    $display("b=%0d",b);
  endtask
endclass

module top;
  sample smpl;
  ext_sample e_smpl;
  initial begin
     
     e_smpl=new();
     smpl=e_smpl;
 
     smpl.a=10;
     smpl.b=20;
     
     smpl.print();
     e_smpl.print();
    
  end
endmodule



I recommend not using the terms child and parent when talking about class inheritance. Use base and derived. You are declaring two class types sample and ext_sample the latter inherits all of the declarations in sample. So ext_sample has two different print tasks declared.
The statement e_smpl=new(); constructs one class ext_sample object with the two print tasks and stores its handle in the class variable e_smpl. Inheritance lets you store a handle to an object in class variable on any base class type, but you will only be able to access the declarations defined by the base type.
This is a very complex topic and I suggest a few other resources:
https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2013/07/16/class-on-classes/
https://verificationacademy.com/topics/systemverilog/systemverilog-oop-for-uvm-verification/
